# Femtosecond photography

Tags: optics, relativity

My question regards comments made around the 9:23 minute mark in Ramesh Raskar's TED talk, "[Imaging at a trillion frames per second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_9vd4HWlVA)".

At [this](https://youtu.be/Y_9vd4HWlVA?t=563) point in the talk, an image shows "light ripples" that move away from the femtosecond camera-- the result of events entering the camera in "reversed order". Raskar goes on to say that the direction of the light ripples is due to a relativistic effect of "space and time warp". His comments about recording at nearly the speed of light and his mentioning of Einstein also seem to imply a relativistic effect.

After thinking about the effect, it seems to me that the observed reversal of ripple direction might be due to the tapered neck of the coke bottle. This taper could make for a lesser to-camera travel time for photons headed toward the tapered neck, then the to-camera travel time of photons that are headed for a wider point along the neck. As a result, if two neighboring photons are initially headed forward toward the bottle's cap and then both are scattered, the photon with the shortest in-bottle path length (perhaps the photon that advances further toward the bottle cap) could reach the camera first. This hypothesis would attribute the overall effect to the shape of the bottle, and the differing speeds of light inside and outside the bottle.

I would like to clarify if the reversed ripple phenomenon is, or is not, caused by relativistic effects. I would also like to clarify Raskar's use of "reversed order". Does this refer to the ordering of captured photons relative to their departure time from the main forward-traveling laser pulse?

Comment: Pssst! Don't tall anyone... it's not news that MIT doesn't hire the best physicists. I would agree with you that there are absolutely no relativistic effects in this work, pretty and enlightening as it is... nothing here moves, hence relativity never comes into play. The entire sequence of images can be reconstructed with simple geometric distances and raytracing. I think your explanation is correct.

Comment: @CuriousOne He isn't a physicist, he's a computer scientist.

Comment: @Brionius: I would make the same comment. It's OK... it's still pretty and I am glad someone is doing this stuff, even if they are mistaking stroboscopic effects or scattering for relativity once in a while.

Comment: I am interested for answer to this too, nobody has an explanation to this. It might be just problem with images processing at such high rate I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Stroboscopes are the ideal method for showing [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), which occurs in signal processing whenever the frequencies exceed half the acquisition frame rate.

I don't see how the effect shown in the TED Talk is relatavistic.  It looks like an aliasing problem to me, though with the data being reconstructed it is hard to say.

If you follow the link in my profile you'll find my dissertation, in which I acquired electron diffraction images at a trillion frames per second, using an ultrafast laser as the strobe. I didn't have to reconstruct any images as I worked with the direct data. Some colleagues worked with streak cameras, similar to the one at MIT, but faster.  The MIT group has different objectives, and used computation to reconstruct the streak camera images.